# Can browsers be called rest client

Tags: http, rest-client

If browsers use http to connect to server ,and in any web application when we hit the  URL and the request is received by a controller mapped to the URL ,can we say browsers are also rest client

Answer (score 0):

That would depend entirely on what you use as a browser but generally no, a browser lacks meaningful tooling to probe a RESTful server out of the box, and comes with features that otherwise would not be needed by a REST client application, so would not be considered a REST client. A browser might be considered as a more generic HTTP client, but even that does not fully describe the problem domain of a browser (rendering, scripting, etc.). Even if you build a web interface to probe a REST service by submitting forms, that does not make the browser a REST client, but instead your website/web application would be the REST client application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
the protocol the browser uses to communicate with the webserver clearly initially is a restful protocol.

Nothing more is necessary.

But it can get a bit more complicated.
The browser can fetch application code (javascript) in a restful way (e.g. GET) and execute that code which further can be communicating (Ajax) restful.